# OnAppear only once the view is opened

Tags: swift, swiftui, onappear

I want to update the view with data when a view is opened so I added:

```
.onAppear {
    loadData()
}
```

But I only want to update it once when the view gets opened not every time it gets reopened e.g. with a back button.

--> Only update on App start

Comment: Add a property to keep track off if it has been loaded yet or if the data loaded is already present?

Comment: My goal is something like 'if firstTimeOpened { .onAppear { code...

Comment: It won't work with a property to keep track because the data gets stored in different CoreData entities and it can't be verified if the data is already up to date

Comment: you were saying `loadData` is getting called each time view appears if you just one to do it once add one bool property to maintain state that data is loaded or not

Comment: If you can't verify that the data is up to date then don't you need to reload it anyway each time the view appears?

Comment: No because it is daily API data and it doesn't make sense to update it every 2 minutes when clicking through views

Comment: Keep track of appear time  in your model then each time appear called check to see for how long it is since last appear.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Initialize app with an Async function | SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68668770/initialize-app-with-an-async-function-swiftui)

Comment: Why cant you use init instead of onappear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var firstTime = true
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
        
        }
        .onAppear(){
            if firstTime {
                // this is the first time app did start
                loadData()
                firstTime = false
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put the value in UserDefaults so you will know in the second load that you have already performed loading.

```
extension UserDefaults {
    
    var firstTimeVisit: Bool {
        get {
            return UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "firstTimeVisit") as? Bool ?? true
        } set {
            UserDefaults.standard.setValue(newValue, forKey: "firstTimeVisit")
        }
    }
    
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            
        }.task {
            if UserDefaults.standard.firstTimeVisit {
                // load Data
                UserDefaults.standard.firstTimeVisit = false
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

```
extension UserDefaults {
    
    var firstTimeVisit: Bool {
        get {
            return !UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "firstTimeVisit")
        } set {
            
            UserDefaults.standard.set(newValue, forKey: "firstTimeVisit")
        }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Please do not suggest KVC with `UserDefaults`. There is `bool(forKey:` and `set(_:forKey:`)

Comment: Good morning, I‘m new in swift. Why is KVC not good or what is the alternative to @azamsharp‘s code?

Comment: @SocialProcessing vadian mentioned that in his comment. Note that this solution will set the property once and store it so next time the app is started nothing will be downloaded so you will need some logic to handle that as well in case it’s a new day.